# Performance of LazyColumn with LazyRows inside it

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I have a lazy column with lazy rows inside it, like in the image:

[image]

I am testing on a 2017 middle-quality phone with Android 9. Release build with R8 enabled.

Scroll performance in rows are pretty good, but in column performance is very low. I am using simplest composables, nothing special.

```
LazyColumn { 
     items(
          items = rows,
          key = { it.id },
          contentType = { it.type}
     ) { 
          LazyRow {
               items(videos) {
                    Video()
               }
          }
     }
 }
```

**update**: this is what [Profile GPU rendering speed](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/inspect-gpu-rendering#profile_rendering) looks like:

[image]

**update**: this is what profiler system trace looks like. I can't figure out what is causing this huge lag:

[image]

**update**: I used a simple **Text** instead of **Video** and still performance is very very poor. I created a [sample project](https://github.com/mrzbn/LazyComposeTest).

Comment: Any solution on this. I am also facing similar issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75835053/android-compose-lazyrow-inside-lazycolumn-gives-junk-behaviour

Comment: @nilkash not yet.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when playing with it months ago. I see some coworkers used ImmutableList for the items though and had better luck with that. Might be worth a try - the issue I had is that there was a ton of recomposition happening as well so make sure that is good with a profiler

Comment: I have to ask a question, why not use a recyclerview for all lists? I think jetpack compose is not suitable for those tasks imho.

Comment: It’s much nicer to work with in terms of  ease of use, flexibility, and extending product features - just have to be careful with the performance here

Comment: @kuck1 tried [ImmutableList](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.collections.immutable) but still list is very laggy.

Comment: Could you provide more details of what data is in `rows`? I'm wondering if something in it could be changing for instance causing a lot of recomposition. Another thing to try is use less data to understand what is happening. Like what if you have 5 rows and 3 items in each - does it work then? Then you can try tracing the performance when it gets to a size that is beginning to break: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance/tracing

Also: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance/bestpractices#defer-reads

@Uriel may be right if you need to render too much

Comment: Depending on your size needs, another thing I found helped was either using a non lazy Col with lazy rows, or vice versa to make scrolling smooth but start up slightly worse

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the sample project with 1000x1000 items seems like overkill. I suggest incorporating pagination as a solution.

Here's an example of pagination in jetpack compose:

https://github.com/MrNtlu/JetpackCompose-Pagination

---

Also might be useful to review official documents:

[Paging library overview](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-overview)

[androidx.paging.compose](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/compose/package-summary#collectaslazypagingitems)

Comment: I think you're mistaking the purpose of paging library. I think it's goal is to gradually load "data", not ui.