# Android compose LazyRow inside LazyColumn gives junk behaviour

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, android-compose-layout

I am trying to create one compose screen with nested scroll behaviour. For that I am using lazyColumn as parent and inside that I do have multiple rows with layRow.

```
val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()
LazyColumn(
    state = scrollState,
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.White),
)
{
    items(100, key = { it })
    {
        LazyRow(
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp)
        ) {

            items(10, key = { it }) {
                Text(text = "Text $it")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting lagging behaviour when I scroll the list. I tried to create release build and saw some improvement but the behaviour is still show some junk behaviour. Behaviour is different on different types of devices.

I tried to use Column as parent view and saw good improvement but it loads all the views in list together. Which cost some other delaying issues.

When I did macro-benchmarking found plenty of junky frames. Majority of them are requesting for render operation.

[image]

[image]

Any optimisation suggestion here?

Comment: What is the data size you used? Is it heavy UI with full images? Or this is happening with the basic code that u shared?

Comment: It is happening with the basic code which I have shared. The junk frames data is also for the same.

Comment: Can you try with your release builds once? I found this topic at the end of the lazy column page and figured out that sometimes it’s poor on performance during debug build but somehow it’s optimised on release https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#measuring-performance, weird but something to give it a shot!

Comment: Also see if R8 optimisation is in place or not.

Comment: @JeelVankhede I tried in release build and there is some improvement in release build. But still it is not performant as recycler view. I can still see some frame drop logs in release build as well. R8 is also enabled.

Comment: Using `Lazy` for rows if your row items are small and its items are simple is just an overkill, IMHO consider using a simple `Row` for them.